# AutoMapper only map when target field is null

Tags: c#, automapper, automapping

Is there any option in AutoMappper to only map properties when the target field is null. i.e. only map properties that aren't already set?

I was hoping to do this without having to write an expression for each individual property.

Any help would be appreciated.

Matt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PinHead877 answer did point me very close but the actual answer was more like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>() .ForAllMembers(r => r.Condition((source, target, sourceField, targetField) => targetField == null));
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>().ForAllMembers(r=>r.Condition(v=>v.DestinationValue==null));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This was close, the actual mapping was something like this: `cfg.CreateMap<TypeA, TypeB>()
                .ForAllMembers(r => r.Condition((source, target, sourceField, targetField) => targetField == null));`

Answer (score 0):

[Conditional mapping](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Conditional-mapping) will help you to achieve this.